# MessageBox в PascalABC.Net

Tags: pascal, .net, pascalabc.net

Я сделал messagebox для придупреждения пользователя о удалении записи. При нажатии Yes - удаляется запись. При нажатии NO - просто должен закрытся messagebox и запись не должа быть удалена.

Вот код:

```
if MessageBox.Show('Удалить запись?','Внимание',MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question)=DialogResult.Yes then
```

Дело в том, что есть ошибка в DialogResult.Yes. Ошибка такая:
Нельзя обратиться к статическому полю Yes через объект.

Кто подскажет что тут не так?

Comment: Никто не знает?

Comment: Может почитать справку про `MessageBox.Show`?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Уже разобрался. Надо записывать полностью: system.windows.forms.dialogresult.yes